# Stockfish: PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

Tags: python, chess, stockfish

I am coding a chess game with the stockfish AI. However whenever i try to iport the library i get the error PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied. I have searched up the error and havent found anything that has fixed my issue. I am pretty new to python so simple answers would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

```py
from stockfish import Stockfish
stockfish = Stockfish(r"/users/meyer/appdata/local/programs/python/python39/lib/site-packages/stockfish")
```

And this is the error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\meyer\Desktop\Python\Chess\Chess ai.py", line 3, in <module>
    stockfish = Stockfish(r"/users/meyer/appdata/local/programs/python/python39/lib/site-packages/stockfish")
  File "C:\Users\meyer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\stockfish\models.py", line 35, in __init__
    self.stockfish = subprocess.Popen(
  File "C:\Users\meyer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\meyer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

Comment: which os do you use? Linux?

Comment: Windows 10, and I don't use Python in a vitual environment.

Comment: maybe add `.exe`  at the end of the stockfish.

Comment: I tried it and it gave me FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified. I think it's because stockfish is a file not a folder.

Comment: check this [link](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/31995/unable-to-run-stockfish-on-python) it may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks so much it worked. For the future, how would you recommend i rearch for my issues in the future, because I only searched for the error?

Comment: https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/31995/unable-to-run-stockfish-on-python
This is the fix, thank you Giorgi Imerlishvili.

Comment: The problem seems to be that you create the stockfish object with the wrong path. `/users/meyer/...` type paths are usually unix paths, so won't work on Windows.